# Проверить соответсвует ли строка шаблону

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, строки, сравнение

Есть шаблон

```
string mask = @"?????;8595??????;4501*;7005*;7701*;800???????;1505???";
```

И есть входная строка

```
string number = "70050045";
```

Нужно определить, соответствует ли эта строка шаблону. Шаблон и строка взяты для примера. 
Использовать regex? Но как преобразовать шаблон? Или есть еще какой-то способ сравнить? Спасибо.

Comment: А что означают символы в вашем шаблоне? Укажите правила интерпретации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположим, что ваш `?` означает «любая *цифра*», `*` означает «ноль или более цифр», `;` означает «или». В таком случае вашу маску легко превратить в регулярное выражение.

```
string mask = @"?????;8595??????;4501*;7005*;7701*;800???????;1505???";
string processedMask =
    "^(" + // исключаем сопоставление в середине
    mask.Replace(';', '|')     // ; == или
        .Replace("?", "\\d")   // ? == одна цифра
        .Replace("*", "\\d*")  // * == ноль или больше цифр
 + ")$";  //  исключаем сопоставление в середине

var regex = new Regex(processedMask);
```

Теперь проверять просто:

```
string number = "70050045";
bool isGood = regex.IsMatch(number);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! То, что нужно! Я практически так и сделала: mask.Replace(";", "$|").Replace("?", "[0-9]").Replace("*", "([0-9]*)") + "$";  Только использовала статику Regex.IsMatch(); разницы ведь нет?

Comment: @Daria: Ну, если регулярку планируется использовать очень часто, то можно создать `Regex` с `RegexOptions.Compiled`, будет быстрее за счёт дополнительного расхода памяти.

Comment: @Daria: И в вашем варианте нету `^`, поэтому он должен принимать строки наподобие `"whatever11111117005"`.

Comment: Да, сейчас использую такой вариант: "^" + mask.Replace(";", "$|^").Replace("?", "[0-9]").Replace("*", "([0-9]*)") + "$". Т.е. добавлять ^ и | для каждого варианта, а не только для всей строки в общем.